# how to select records matching current date and hour of timestamp column in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to oracle DB and writing sql queries. I have timestamp column in Table. I need to select the records which matches to current date and hour ignoring rest of timestamp value. 
i found a way with trunc function as below which is giving me the records matching criteria

```
    select * from TABLE where trunc(COLUMN_NAME,'HH') = trunc(systimestamp,'HH')
```

I came to know that above query wont use indexes if any, on that coulmn. pls guide me with efficient query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: guide me for this issue .....thnks in advance

Comment: Search in google with "how to select records matching current date and hour of timestamp column in oracle" .. You will get enough records